# PHP Count Between Date and Todays Date

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my `dates` database I have a table of dates that have two followups to be completed, one after 30 days, one after 60 days. I need to build a page that uses the MySQL query to pull all dates from the `dates` table that have a `30day` value of `No` (which I can do). Now the tricky part is, I need it to only output the dates that meet that criteria, and are 30 days from the current date.

For example: August 4 & 6 have a `30day` value of `No`, August 5 has a `30day` value of `Yes`. Today's date is September 4. 30-days prior would be August 5.

I need the query to only display August 4 in this case, since it hasn't been 30 days since August 6 and August 5 has already been done.

I am unsure what kind of function to use to do this counting. I appreciate your help

**EDIT:**

```
Date - 30day Value
July 1 - Yes
July 5 - No
August 1 - No
August 5 - No
August 6 - Yes
```

Today's Date is September 2.

The table would display July 5 and August 1, as their 30day values are No, and they are more than 30 days from todays date.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp  . this will help you directly get data through query only

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have an example in my post in regards to date in August. I would like a table to export any dates past 30 days that have a 30-day value of No.

Comment: @BrandinArsenault . . . I made my comment because for me, it would be much clearer to see sample data and desired results, rather than sentences describing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I hope my edit helps.

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer by clicking the little checkbox if it is correct and optionally up vote, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's `DATEDIFF` function allows you to subtract 2 dates in a query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

> `DATEDIFF()` returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

For example:

```
SELECT some_id, date_column
FROM date_table
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_column) = 30
```

You could also select both 30 and 60 days like this and also have a cutoff date of 60 days so it's not searching the whole table:

```
SELECT some_id, date_column
FROM date_table
WHERE date_column>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_column) IN (30, 60)
```

And since I'm making some assumptions with my understanding of what you're asking, you may also want to do this which will return the results as 'Yes' or 'No' in your result set:

```
SELECT some_id, date_column,
CASE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_column)
    WHEN 60 THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN 30 THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
END CASE AS is_3060_day
FROM date_table
WHERE date_column>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

Alternatively if you want to accomplish this on the PHP side, you could use PHP's `date_diff` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

```
function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat = '%a' )
{
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format($differenceFormat);

}
$result = dateDifference($date1, $date2)
if ($result==30 || $result==60) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Hands down one of the best and most detailed answers I have ever seen. Thank you Clayton, so much!

Answer (score 2):

You should use **DATEDIFF** function:

```
SELECT ....
FROM your_table
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), event_date) = 30
```

Where **event_date** is example of your date column.

Answer (score 1):

you can fetch both the dates and use the php function

```
$prevdate = date_create("2013-03-15");
$currdate = date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff = date_diff($prevdate,$currdate);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
```

Output

```
272 days
```